# Finding probability of earning points

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

A professor asks a true/false question with ten individual questions. Suppose the professor assigns grades of: $10$ points for each correct response, $0$ points for each absent response, and $-10$ for each incorrect response, but where negative totals are always replaced by zero. Les Guess, a student who understands nothing of the professor's class, flips a fair coin to decide if he will answer each question true or false.

a) In how many different ways might Les answer the question?

b) What is the probability that Les Guess will earn $n$ points? (This is just the number of ways to answer the question that will result in n points divided by the total number of ways of answering the question.)

Comment: Is there a chance that he will not answer a question? Or is every question answered either true or false? The wording is a little ambiguous: what he is flipping for exactly?

Comment: Is it possible that he will not answer, or does the coin flip force him to answer?  For b it sounds like you are asking only about this question-does the round up to zero apply?

Comment: I believe based on the wording of the question, he has to answer because he is flipping a coin and therefore he will choose either true or false depending on what the coins lands on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will (for the moment) assume that he picks true, false, or abstain equally likely. (otherwise, why mention the abstain possibility?)

(a) There are $3$ possibilities for each question, so there are $3^{10}$ ways to take the test.

(b) To score $10n$, he needs to answer $k$ questions right and $k-n$ answers wrong. So the number of ways is

$${10 \choose k} {{10-k} \choose {k-n}}$$

for $0 \le k \le 10$, where ${ x \choose 0}=1$, ${x \choose {j<0}} = 0$, and ${0 \choose 10\ge j\ge0} = 1$.

Then the total probability is

$$P(10n) = \frac{1}{3^{10}}\sum_{k=0}^{10} {10 \choose k} {{10-k} \choose {k-n}}$$

for $n > 0$. This is symmetric with $n < 0$ and the probability of having equal numbers of rights and wrongs is given by the above definition of $P(10n)$ by setting $n=0$.

**Other interpretation**

Now I will assume that he chooses true or false equally likely and never abstains.

(a) There are $2^{10}$ ways to take the test.

(b) Let $r$ denote the number of correct answers and $w$ the number of wrong answers. Say he scores $10n$. We have that

$$r+w = 10 \\ r - w = n$$

So if $n$ is odd, there are no ways. If $n$ is even, then $r=5+n/2$ and $w = 5-n/2$. We now choose $r$ of the $10$ questions to be correct, so there are ${10 \choose {5+n/2}}$ ways to take the test while scoring $n$. So the probability is:

$$
   P(10n) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{1}{2^{10}}{10 \choose {5+n/2}} & : \text{n even}\\
       0 & : \text{n odd}
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

for $1 \le n \le 10$. For $n=0$, we can score negative or $0$. Negative n is symmetric with the positive $n$, and ${10 \choose 5}$ is the number of ways to get exactly $0$, so

$$P(0)=\frac{1}{2^{10}}{10 \choose 5} + \sum_{n=1}^{10} P(10n)$$

Comment: I see. Now I'm trying to find what the expected number of points that Les will earn? I know this is just the sum, over
all possible number of points, of that number of points times the the probability of earning it. But I'm not quite sure how to write it though.

Comment: From the definition of expected value: $E=\sum_{n=1}^{10} 10n * P(10n)$. Then you can plug in my expression. Disclaimer: I would test my expression for a few values to make sure it makes sense. (I make errors too often).